# setting different images based on screen size using css

Tags: html, css

I have following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Media Elements</title>
</head>
<body>

<img id="upay_image" src="" style="width:100%; height:auto;">

</body>
</html>
<style>
@media(min-width: 415px)
    {
        #upay_image
        {
            content:url(images/iPadSizeGif.gif);
            border:1px solid red;
        }

    }
    @media(max-width: 414px)
    {
        #upay_image
        {
            border:1px solid black;
            content:url(images/iPhoneSizeGif.gif);
        }

    }


</style>
```

I am going to change image based on different screen sizes. However, it is only showing iPad size. Please, help me where am i doing a mistake?

Comment: Write CSS for general view without media query

Comment: You can use similar like this : - https://fiddle.jshell.net/0yavt0kg/

Comment: first you need to set content without media Query , then you can add content for your specified screens

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/0yavt0kg/2/ and https://fiddle.jshell.net/0yavt0kg/1/ are two options to change image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options to changes images to different resolutions.
First is

```css
#upay_image{
  background-image:url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg");
  background-size:100% 100%;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

@media(max-width: 768px){
  #upay_image{
  background-image:url("https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png");
   }
}
@media(max-width: 500px){
  #upay_image{
  background-image:url("http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/08/22/006F877400000258-3482989-image-a-10_1457476109735.jpg");
}
}
```

```html
<img id="upay_image" src="">
```

Second options is

```css
.Ipad,.Mobile{display:none;}

@media(max-width: 768px){
  .Desktop,.Mobile{
    display:none;
  }
  .Ipad{
    display:block;
  }
}
@media(max-width: 500px){
  .Desktop,.Ipad{
    display:none;
  }
  .Mobile{
    display:block;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" class="Desktop">
<img   src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png" class="Ipad">
<img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2016/03/08/22/006F877400000258-3482989-image-a-10_1457476109735.jpg" class="Mobile">
```